# Tweepy Cursor vs Iterative for low API calls

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am writing a simple [Tweepy](http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/) application for fun, but am really limited to how many API calls I have (anywhere between 150 and 350). So to account for this I am looking for ways to cut calls. Tweepy has a cursor system built in. Eg:

```
# Iterate through all of the authenticated user's friends
for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items():
    follower.follow()
```

For those who are familiar with this library. Would the above example be more or less efficient than simply...

```
for follower in api.followers_ids():
    api.follow(follower)
```

Are there any other advantages apart from simplicity to use the Cursor method over an iterative method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly from my use of `tweepy`, a `Cursor` object automatically paginates over `n` many elements... For instance, if there are 10,000 results, and Twitter returns (say) 200 at a time, then using the `Cursor` will return all 10,000 but will have to make a call to keep retrieving the next ones.

OTOH, `api.followers_ids()` only returns the first "page" of results, so maybe the first 100 or whatever.

Comment: api.followers_ids() will only return the first 5000 users, so it is safe to assume it's not a factor. Which would be best in that case?