# Full list of twitter "friends" using python and tweepy

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

By friends I mean all of the twitter users who I am following.

Is it possible using tweepy with python 2.7.6 to display a full list of all friends?

I have found it possible to display a list which contains some of my friends with the following code.  After handling authorization of course.

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
user = api.get_user('MyTwitterHandle')
print "My Twitter Handle:" , user.screen_name
ct = 0

for friend in user.friends():
    print friend.screen_name
    ct = ct + 1


print "\n\nFinal Count:", ct
```

This code successfully prints what appears to be my 20 most recent friends on Twitter, the `ct` variable is equal to 20. This method excludes the rest of the users I am following on Twitter.

Is it possible to display all of the users I am following on twitter? Or at least a way to adjust a parameter to allow me to include more friends?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/c9a7ba3d77979415c2f1b983a5ba7900536d8606/tweepy/api.py#L487), `friends()` is referred to the [`GET friends / list`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/list) twitter endpoint, which allows a `count` parameter to be passed in:

> The number of users to return per page, up to a maximum of 200. Defaults to 20.

This would allow you to get 200 friends via `friends()`.

Or, better approach would be to use a `Cursor` which is a [paginated way](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/docs/code_snippet.rst#pagination) to get all of the friends:

```
for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends).items():
    # Process the friend here
    process_friend(friend)
```

See also:

- [incomplete friends list](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/445)
- [Tweepy Cursor vs Iterative for low API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213548/tweepy-cursor-vs-iterative-for-low-api-calls)

Comment: The cursor method seems to work for this application, is it also limited to 200 but by default?

Comment: @John nope, it is not limited to 200.

Comment: @alecxe How much paging requests can we made? If any user have 5000 followers then if paging limit will be 100 set then twitter is giving "Twitter limit reached."